# Combining WordPress pagination functions for archives and search results

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I am currently modernising an old WordPress theme (a standalone theme, not a child of any official themes). Trying to build pagination I am finding some issues creating one function that works for both archives and search. The first snippet works fine with archives (categories, loops, etc):

```
function pagination_bar() {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'      => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format'    => 'page/%#%',
            'current'   => $current_page,
            'total'     => $total_pages,
            'prev_text' => __('« Previous page'),
            'next_text' => __('Next page »'),
        ));
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I use in search results pages the links end up being `domain.com/?s=QUERYpage/2` (whilst it should be `domain.com/page/2/?s=query`)

So I created a custom function just for pagination in search:

```
function pagination_bar_search() {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'      => get_home_url() . '%_%',
            'format'    => '/page/%#%/',
            'current'   => $current_page,
            'total'     => $total_pages,
            'prev_text' => __('« Previous page'),
            'next_text' => __('Next page »'),
        ));
    }
}
```

Both work correctly, but do you have any ideas for how I can combine the 2 functions and make one that works correctly for both archives and search?

I'm on the latest WordPress (5.2.3).

This is the `search.php` loop function:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1)
echo 'Page ' . $paged.' of '.$wp_query->max_num_pages; 
?>

...

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

...

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php pagination_bar_search(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Examples):

> To add pagination to your *search results and archives*, you can use
>   the following example:
>
> ```
> <?php
> global $wp_query;
>
> $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
>
> echo paginate_links( array(
>   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
>   'format' => '?paged=%#%',
>   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
>   'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
> ) );
> ?>
> ```

So based on that, I modified your function:

```php
function pagination_bar( $query = null ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $query ?
        $query->max_num_pages :
        $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'   => $current_page,
            'total'     => $total_pages,
            'prev_text' => __( '« Previous page' ),
            'next_text' => __( 'Next page »' ),
        ) );
    }
}
```

and it worked well, both with archives and search results.

I also added support for custom query (i.e. `new WP_Query`), so that you could for example do:

```php
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( ... ) );
pagination_bar( $my_query );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem even after using the above approach, the problem for me isn't coming from the WP_Query Class or the pagination.

I just figured out that the **offset** parameter ignores and breaks the **paged** parameter and the whole pagination, and the thing is I can't let go of the **offset** parameter as my theme structure relies on it. Is there any solution for this matter?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same format rather than using a query argument, I added a check in the function to see if we are on a search page or not and modified the base and format.

```
/**
 * Numbered pagination
 */
function so_348298_pagination_links() {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
        $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

        $base = get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '%_%';
        $format = 'page/%#%';

        if (is_search()) {
            $base = get_home_url() . '%_%';
            $format = '/page/%#%/';
        }

        echo '<div class="pagination-links col-12 text-center mb-5">' .
             paginate_links( array(
                 'base'    => $base,
                 'format'  => $format,
                 'current' => $current_page,
                 'total'   => $total_pages,
                 'type'    => 'list',
             ) ) .
             '</div>';
    }
}
```