# i cant see the max_num_pages of a custom wp query

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

i hope you help me with this,

i am making a wordpress website witch has 3 diffrent post types(the regular post type and 2 others), i have the pagenation work very with in the regular posts page, but it does not work in the other 2 page of the other custom posts, when i tried to solve this out i found that the problem is that like the custom query object does not have the `max_num_pages` attribute, when i echo the value of it, it does not show of ,
look at my code!

this is the custom query i made:

```
                            $currentpage = get_query_var('paged');
                            $myQuery= new WP_Query(array(
                                    'post_type'         => 'airdrop',
                                    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
                                    'paged'             => $currentpage 
                            ))


                                 function my_pagination(){
                                    $all_pages = $myQuery->max_num_pages;
                                    $current_page = max(1 , get_query_var('paged'));
                                    echo $current_page ."/". $all_pages;
                                    if ($all_pages>1) {
                                        return paginate_links(array(
                                            'base'      =>get_pagenum_link() .'%_%',
                                            'format'    =>'page/%#%',
                                            'current'   =>$current_page
                                        ));
                                    }
                                }
                                echo my_pagination();
```

if you look at this line `echo $current_page ."/". $all_pages;`
this should print something `like 1 / 2 or 1 /3` ,
but it shows only `1 / blank` and the num_max not shwing,
i hope you help me figure it out

***EDIT :***

even this simple codeisn't working

```
                           $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                                    'post_type'         => 'airdrop',
                                    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
                            ));
                            echo $loop->max_num_comment_pages;
```

Comment: `$myQuery` is defined outside and isn't accessible from within `my_pagination()`.

Comment: why isn't accessible, it's global

Comment: I would suggest you to change your pagination function to support custom `WP_Query` objects/instances like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/348315/137402) - and in your case, you could simply change your function to `function my_pagination( $myQuery )` and then when you call the function, supply the `WP_Query` instance like so: `my_pagination( $myQuery )`. And looking at your current answer, that's an example problem of using global variables - when the same variable is assigned to another `WP_Query` instance, then you'd run into issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are not in functions scope.

My example of function:

```
function customPagination($paged = '', $max_page = '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    if( ! $paged )
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');

    if( ! $max_page )
    $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'total' => $max_page,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'prev_text'  => false,
        'next_text'  => false,
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'mid_size' => 3
    ) );
}
```

and then calling it with your variables (just changed to camelCase)

```
customPagination($currentPage, $myQuery->max_num_pages);
```

Hope it helps

## Heading

Comment: I don't think so, because the $loop object is global in the file, so any function in the file could use it

Comment: i tryed it it's not working eather

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer :
what i was doing wrong is that i have two wp_query objects with the same name ($loop).

when first  i made the two posts type i gave theme same name, this is why it gets confused,

> the solution is that never use two or more wp_query with the same
>   name!!!